# Qt How to build SQLite driver

Tags: sqlite, qt

I am developing in Windows using Qt.

I am currently using Qt version 5.11.3. This comes with a SQLite driver for version 3.24.0. I would like to rebuild the driver using the latest version of SQLite (3.34.0), which I have downloaded to C:\SQLite.

I have downloaded the Qt sources using the Maintenance tool but cannot work out how to build the driver.

Qt is installed at C:\Qt. After checking the README in C:\Qt\5.11.3\Src which came with the sources and the [Qt Documentation about building database drivers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers), I have opened a command window and executed the following:

```
cd C:\Qt\5.11.3\Src
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin
configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -nomake tests -nomake examples -skip qtwebengine -opensource -confirm-license
cd qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers
\Qt\5.11.3\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -- -system-sqlite SQLITE3_PREFIX=C:\SQLite
```

This fails with

> Project ERROR: You cannot configure sqldrivers separately within a top-level build.

What have I done wrong? What should I do differently?

Comment: I'm sure that updating to a more recent version of Qt will bring a driver that includes a more recent version of SQLite. Soon, however, SQLite will produce another version and I'll need to rebuild the driver if I want to use it and will face the same problem.

Comment: Doesn't `SQLITE3_PREFIX` need to be added to the `configure` parameters?

Comment: Where? How? If I add SQLITE3_PREFIX=... to the beginning of my command line, I get an error that looks as though it comes from the cmd shell. If I add it at the end, I get `ERROR: Assigning unknown variable 'SQLITE3_PREFIX' on command line.` from the configure script.

Comment: OK. I can add SQLITE_PREFIX=... to the end of the configure command line. (Note SQLITE_PREFIX, not SQLITE3_PREFIX.)

Comment: It appears that to get rid of the "You cannot configure..." error, you need to delete a file that `qmake` creates as part of running `configure` before running `qmake` explicitly.. I actually deleted `.qmake.super`, but it may be sufficient to get rid of `.qmake.cache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to build a SQLite driver for Qt successfully.

As ever, having solved this type of problem, everything seems so obvious that it's hard to pin down what constituted the breakthrough.

I received quite a bit of advice in [this thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/121798/fun-and-games-building-qsqlite-for-qt-5-15-0) on the Qt forums. Some very helpful, and some... Probably the most useful thing I was told was that it is not necessary to execute the `configure` command about which I originally asked for help.

I still encountered several problems, which were probably due to my own unfamiliarity with `bash` scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Building SQLite from scratch has been a arduous experience for me. It's a complex, finicky process that requires you to install Tcl on your computer (https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/).

I recommend using MSVC and build it from the command line, as described by SQLite. It's "easier" and quicker than doing it from Qt Creator. You can just link to sqlite3.lib and include sqlite3.dll in your run directory.

Here is a command file; change the directory names to reflect the Visual Studio version you are using.

Note:

- Copy `tcl86t.lib` to `tcl86.lib`
- Make sure there are no blanks in the directory name where the SQLite source has been unzipped.
- Skip the SET PATH statements if you are re-running multiple times, it will compound.

```
cls
:: to find cl.exe, rc.exe
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\ActiveTcl\bin

SET NMAKE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\nmake.exe"
:: Assumes source was unzipped in "C:\SQLite"
SET SQL=C:\SQLite

SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include
:: windows.h, winresrc.h
SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um
:: winapifamily.h
SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared
:: tcl.h
SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\ActiveTcl\include

SET LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64
SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64
SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64
SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\ActiveTcl\lib

CD $SQL%
IF NOT EXIST bld mkdir bld
:: Safer to delete previous runs, appears to not be able to overwrite
del /S /Q bld\*.* >NUL
cd bld

%NMAKE% /f "%SQL%\Makefile.msc" TOP=..\sqlite >error.log
%NMAKE% /f "%SQL%\Makefile.msc" sqlite3.c TOP=..\sqlite >>error.log
%NMAKE% /f "%SQL%\Makefile.msc" sqlite3.dll TOP=..\sqlite >>error.log
%NMAKE% /f"%SQL%\Makefile.msc" sqlite3.exe TOP=..\sqlite >>error.log
%NMAKE% /f"%SQL%\Makefile.msc" test TOP=..\sqlite >>error.log
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I must say that I have experienced no difficulties that I thought lay with the SQLite build, and all my problems were associated with the Qt side of things. I apologise for not previously answering my own question as I have now successfully built an SQLite driver for Qt.